# Vb net bytearray is to short to receive an image

Tags: arrays, vb.net, image

I need to receive and image from a socket in a project but the bytearray supposed to store the image is too short. (I have reached the maximum length of a byte array). Is there any way to extend the length of a byte array in visual basic or do I need to separate the image in multiple parts ?
here are the code :

vb.net

```
Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = 2147483647
Dim bytesFrom(2147483647) As Byte
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
```

java (for android)

```java
try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), picUri);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                sendMessage("[IMAGE FLAG]");

                sleep(1000);

                sendMessage(bytes);
                /*for(int i=0;i>bytes.length;i++){
                    byte byteCutted = bytes[i];
                    sendMessage(byteCutted);
                }*/
                Log.d("MESSAGE","ALL BYTES ARE SENT");

            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

sendMessage() is just a function that open a socket and send the specified parameter.

As you can see, Even by decreasing the image quality in the java code, the vb net bytearray is still to short.

Comment: That seems unlikely. Start by showing us the code, which we should NEVER have to ask for.

Comment: Sorry that's true, I edited the post.

Comment: It should be noted that 2,147,483,647 bytes is one byte less than 2 GiB (GiB based on 1024 where GB based on 1000). Is there really a possibility of receiving an image that large?

Comment: I don't know why but it seems to be not large enough. The pictures I sent were just partially written in a jpeg file and when I used a python script that receive more there was no problem. (Also the ram usage graph of the vb net script was stuck at 2gb so I think the array was full).

Comment: The application memory usage is what's allocated. As soon as you create the array, all the memory is allocated. Every byte in that allocation is set to zero until you set it to something else. It's just like an egg carton takes up room in your fridge, even if there are no eggs in it. Unless your images are 2 GiB or more in size, the array is big enough and something else is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is going to fail when you try to create the array, so you'll never even get to reading the data into it.

Firstly, don't hard code the number 2,147,483,647. Get that from `Integer.MaxValue`.

As for the issue, an array cannot have more than that many elements. When you create an array in VB, you specify the upper bound, not the length. The upper bound is one less than the length so, if you specify `Integer.MaxValue` as the upper bound when creating an array, as you are, an exception will be thrown. When I executed this code:

```vb
Dim length = Integer.MaxValue

Dim arr(length) As Byte
```

there was an `OverflowException` thrown on the second line. I have to assume that your code is doing the same thing. When I did this:

```vb
Dim length = Integer.MaxValue
Dim upperBound = length - 1

Dim arr(upperBound) As Byte
```

there was no `OverflowException`. I still got an `OutOfMemoryException` but that can be remedied by allocating more memory to the application. Once that's done, the array will be created successfully and you can actually get to reading the data.